# How to add single quotes to strings in csv using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

When the below query is executed, its grabs all the data I need however, is there a way to add single quotation marks to the column data called ‘PARTY’. So currently the data in the party column is being presented as **`12105515480000`**. I would like the data to be presented in the CSV as **`‘12105515480000’`**

Could someone show me how to fix this please?

My Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["VT","NCR","N","DT","RD"],
                    "query": {

                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{"range": {"VT": {
                                            "gte": "now/d",
                                            "lte": "now+1d/d"}}},

                                {"wildcard": {"user": "mike*"}}]}}},size=10)


csv_file = 'File_' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d - %H.%M.%S')) + '.csv'


header_names = { 'VT': 'Date',  'NCR': 'ExTime',  'N': 'Name', 'DT': 'Party', ' RD ': 'Period'}

with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header_names.keys(), restval='', extrasaction='ignore')
    w.writerow(header_names,)
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source']

             w.writerow(my_dict)
```

CSV Output

```
Date      ExTime    Party
20171016    1       12105515480000
20171016    1       12105515480000
20171016    0       12105515480000
```

Ideal output

```
Date      ExTime    Party
20171016    1       ‘12105515480000’
20171016    1       ‘12105515480000’
20171016    0       ‘12105515480000’
```

Comment: Looks like the data is numeric. Do you want to only write it to csv as a string, or read it as a string from elasticsearch in the first place?

Comment: write it to CSV as a string so when the CSV file is created i will see under the party column ‘12105515480000’. if that make sense. you able to show me how to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to convert the actual data you want quoted to a string before writing to csv:

```
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    my_dict = doc['_source']
    my_dict['DT'] = str(my_dict['DT'])
    w.writerow(my_dict)
```

and also configure your csv writer to quote non-numeric chars with `'` (not exactly the exact quote characters you used, but I figured that's not a requirement anyway):

```
w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=header_names.keys(), restval='', extrasaction='ignore',
                   quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, quotechar="'")
```

**Edit:** since your data is already in textual form, this solution doesn't work for you. I don't know of any way to only put quotes around certain columns except manually doing it like so:

```
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    my_dict = doc['_source']
    my_dict['DT'] = "'" + my_dict['DT'].replace("'", r"\'") + "'"
    w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: that has added the single quotes but it has added them to all of the columns. is there a way to only add it to DT?

Comment: Can you show your sample data in a format that shows the type (edit the question)? For example `json.dumps`, where we can see whether your data is numeric or textual

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, sorry could you explain.

Comment: It is unclear whether your values like `12105515480000` are actual numbers, or just strings looking like numbers. You only show them being output to CSV, which doesn't show them differently. Can you `print(my_dict)` and show its output? That will show whether the values are strings or integers. I suspect strings, as otherwise csv wouldn't quote them with the `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` option.

Comment: i have added print(my_dict) and the output i am getting is - 'VT': 'TEST', 'NCR': 'yes', 'DT': '18525488527', as you can see the single quotes are on all columns  not just the DT

Comment: i got a error -      my_dict['DT'] = "'"+ my_dict['DT'].replace("'", r"\'") + "'"
KeyError: 'DT'

Comment: Honestly, Felk if this work then im more than happy even though it might not be the best solution. however i am getting a error.

Comment: I was just guessing the key name. It's possible not all documents contain a `DT`. But that is a different issue.